# Re-centering clockspring 2009 Subaru legacy

Tags: electrical, subaru, steering, abs, interior

My horn no longer works, the steering radio controls no longer work, my airbag light is on. I have a bad clockspring. The dealer wants $650 to install new. *I found a complete steering column with clockspring included for $65 locally*

The used clockspring in the junkyard steering column is not centered so I have no idea how off center it is. I have removed it from the steering column and am ready to start the re-centering procedure

Printed on the clockspring is a procedure for re-centering, to me these instructions are confusing so I'm posting here to get some help understanding how to accomplish this re-centering procedure. Below is a picture of the clockspring and the instructions printed on it.

[image: clockspring]

[image: clockspring closeup instructions]

I've read posts of people saying they have damaged the clockspring by over rotating it. I don't want to do that, supposedly the internals of these clockspring components are delicate.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, those printed instructions say turn 3.25 turns to the right from the left zero position.
That should match with you having the front wheels pointed directly ahead.

Do **not** force against the left zero position, this should rotate easily and just "feel" the stop.

Comment: I turned the inner ring very carefully and slowly and found the left zero position. I do see how someone who’s in a hurry or is not thinking delicate to easily push past and break the left zero position. Turning it back 3 and a quarter turns centered the unit. I put a clamp on it. Now to remove the one from the working car and replace.

Comment: Sounds just right, good luck for the rest.

Comment: After centering and installing the replacement clockspring I now have the horn, radio and cruise control buttons working but the airbag light remains on.

Comment: Been here done that. I did see a clock spring fail in a vehicle once, caused by someone erroneous shorting out a wire with a screw. The short caused some wires to overheat, melt insulation. Turn on car, turn steering wheel, airbag goes boom. So yeah, be careful. Really careful.